# Did Barry affect the timeline during the episode "What's Past Is Prologue"?

Tags: plot-explanation, arrowverse, the-flash

So, I watched **The Flash season 5 episode 8** *(What's Past Is Prologue)*, and one thing got me confused:

*When Barry went back to the time where his speed had been taken by **Hunter Zolomon** (a.k.a Zoom)* and after successfully finding the device, while he was returning from that time with his daughter, Zoom followed them and a **Time-Wraith** caught Zoom inside **'The Speedforce'** *(@16:45 min)*.

Shouldn't that change course of history where his dad *(Henry Allen)* is never killed by Zoom and is alive in the future? (Yeah, time-travelling is tricky ).

Comment: and if is father is alive, he would never went back in past and created flashpoint... Yeah, was wondering exactly the same.

Comment: Yes,like they say when travelling back to time, don't interfere unless necessary. Eventually coming back will always lead to new timeline due to such kind of interference & here was the question about existence of Zoom and it's massive effect on time.

Comment: Since this was the midseason finale, the answer so far is *We don't know. Wait and see.*

Comment: @Taladris, I think we don't have to wait, because it's not like they changed past but never came back to future. They return to exactly same time when they went. I guess it's flaw in this plot. Still waiting for creditable answer *(No offense here)*

Comment: @JeelVankhede: they spend about 10 minutes (the time to fight Cicada) in the present at the end of the midseason finale. We cannot really assess the changes in the timeline from that. Plus, they had to fight a reality-changing cosmic entity less than a week later. And more importantly, what can change the timeline dramatically is up to the writers. Good question anyway

Comment: Yeah, actually i thought that may be i was the only one unclear about this thing, but now i see that we all are !.. I think waiting for upcoming episodes is the answer 